# Rails 3.2 Event Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, data-modeling, event-log

I have a rails application with an administration interface that allows a user CRUD operations on certain models.  The client wants a way to log what user does what to each model.  For example,  A user deletes a customer etc.  He would like to track who deleted/updated/created that customer.  I'm pondering the best way to handle this.  I'm also curious if there is a gem out there that already does this.

Here's my thinking.

1. I could have a created_by and updated_by field in each Model.  The problem
   is tracking deleted_by. One Method is to mark the Customer inactive
   instead of deleting the actual record.  Seems cumbersome and there
   would be a lot of repetition in each and every model I want to
   track.
2. I could create an event_history model that tracked the following fields (class diagram below). The model_record_data field could be stored as an array or object possibly?  Can you store objects in a mysql field as text?  The benefits of this method, to me is that I can call to this Model and store actions from any model I create in the future.  In addition I can restore a record to a previous state if someone makes a mistake.

   ```
   event_history ->
     model_name
     model_record_data
     action             #create/update/delete etc
     action_date        #datetime
     user_id
   ```

I would appreciate some feedback on this and your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this gem (`audited`). I believe it does what are asking.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited